# post запрос с параметрами вручную

Tags: asp.net, post

в контроллере есть метод:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        //public async Task<Users> Post([FromBody] Users user) - тоже пробовал
        public async Task<Users> Post([Bind(Include = "id,FIO,login,password,date_for_last_sign_in")] Users user)
        {
            return user;
        }
```

модель:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string FIO { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public DateTime date_for_last_sign_in { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как проверить работоспособность функции?

Я создал кнопку и пробую так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addUser").click(function () {
        var users = {
            id: 1,
            FIO: "fio",
            login: "log",
            password: "pass",
            date_for_last_sign_in: "2012-04-23T18:25:43"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/values/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(users),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () { alert("error");}
        });
    });
});
```

Получаю пустой объект, почему так может быть ?

Comment: `error: function () { console.log(this); }` - ?

Comment: @Igor добавил в вопрос (появляются при нажатии кнопки)

Comment: Вы на бекенд отправляете массив, когда как он ждёт объект. Либо сделайте чтобы бэкэнд ожидал массив пользователей, либо из jQuery отправляйте объект

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil в `ajax users`  убрать `[ ]`? Или как мне ещё отправить объект? На сколько я знаю если JSON массив соответствует объекту, от MVC само с него объект склепает. Но почему то этого не происходит. Возможно с типом ошибка? Но с каким?

Comment: @SultanovShamil не помогает.. посоветуете еще что-то?